# Show that the $p$-series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ is convergent iff $p \gt 1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Show that the $p$-series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ is convergent iff $p \gt 1$.

**Attempt:**
For the right direction:
Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ is convergent. Then, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^p} = 0$.
In particular, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^p} = 0$ for $p \gt 0$. But, for $0 \lt p \le 1$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ is divergent. Hence, we must have $p \gt 1$. $\Box$

Proof that series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ is divergent:
We know that $n^p \le n$ for all positive integers $n$ and $0 \lt p \le 1$.
Then,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{n^p}.
\end{equation*}
Now, since the partial sums of the harmonic series are not bounded, this
inequality shows that the partial sums of the $p-$series are not bounded when $0 \lt p \le 1$. Hence, the $p-$series diverges for theses values of $p. \Box$

For the left direction:
Let $p \gt 1$. Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^p}$ for all $x \in [1.\infty)$. Then, $f$ is a positive, continous, and decreasing sequence. Hence, we can apply the Integral Test here. Notice that
\begin{align*}
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^p} &= \lim\limits_{b \to \infty} \int_1^b \frac{1}{x^p} \\
&= \lim\limits_{b\to \infty} \left[\frac{1}{1-p}x^{1-p}\right]_1^b \\
&= \lim\limits_{b \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{1-p}b^{1-p} - \frac{1}{1-p} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{p-1} \lim\limits_{b \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{b^{p-1}} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{p-1}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^p}dx
\end{equation*}
is convergent. Consequently, $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}dn$ is convergent. By the Integral Test,
we have that
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}
\end{equation*}
is convergent. $\Box$

Am I correct, especially for the right direction ?

Answer (score 2):

The case where $p \leqslant 0$ is quite simple to establish, so I will look only at the case where $p > 0$.  One way you can establish the convergence/divergence result is by using upper and lower bounds on the summation.  For all values $n \geqslant 1$ and $p>0$ we can easily establish the bounds:

$$\int \limits_{n}^{n+1} \frac{1}{r^p} \ dr \leqslant \frac{1}{n^p} \leqslant \int \limits_{n-1}^n \frac{1}{r^p} \ dr.$$

Applying these bounds to each term in the sum (except for the first term for the upper bound) gives:

$$\int \limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{r^p} \ dr \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p} \leqslant 1 + \int \limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{r^p} \ dr.$$

Solving the definite integral we get:

$$R(p) \equiv \int \limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{r^p} \ dr 
= \begin{cases} 
\infty & & \text{if } 0 < p \leqslant 1, \\[8pt]
\frac{1}{p-1} & & \text{if } p > 1. \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

Substituting this form for the integral we therefore obtain:

$$R(p) \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p} \leqslant 1+R(p).$$

We can now look at the conditions on $p$.  If we have $0 < p \leqslant 1$ then we get:

$$\infty \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p} \leqslant \infty.$$

If we have $p>1$ then we get:

$$\frac{1}{p-1} \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p} \leqslant \frac{p}{p-1}.$$

This establishes that the sum is divergent when $0 < p \leqslant 1$ and convergent when $p>1$.

Comment: Hello Ben, I hope it's going well. Do you think it would be possible for you to explain the established of the first inequality you have a little more in depth, I am still having some trouble comprehending how you got there.

Comment: Actually, I would appreciate an explanation for the proof of...if $f: [1,+\infty] \to \mathbb{R}$ is non-negative/monotone decreasing then for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, one has $\int_1^{N+1} f(x)  dx \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N} f(n) \leq f(1) + \int_1^N f(x) dx$.

Comment: That part uses the "monotonicity property" of integration.  If $f$ is monotone decreasing then you have $f(x) \leqslant f(t)$ for all $x \geqslant t$ so that $\int_{t}^{t+1} f(x) \ dx \leqslant \int_{t}^{t+1} f(t) \ dx = f(t)$.

Comment: Hmm, I am still not seeing the final leap. Would this get me $\sum_{t=1}^N \int_t^{t+1} f(x)dx \leq \sum_{t=1}^N \int_t^{t+1} f(t)dx = \sum_{t=1}^N f(t)$ for the LHS and $\sum_{t=1}^{N-1} \int_t^{t+1} f(x)dx \leq \sum_{t=1}^{N-1} \int_t^{t+1} f(t+1)dx = \sum_{t=1}^{N-1} f(t+1) $ for the RHS?

Comment: Your LHS is equivalent to what I used in the post.  For RHS (where we want the inequality sign to be the other way) we use the alternative inequality $\int_{t-1}^{t} f(x) \ dx \geqslant \int_{t-1}^{t} f(t) \ dx = f(t)$.

Comment: So may I write $\sum_{t=1}^{N-1}f(t) = f(1) + \sum_{t=1}^{N-1}  \int_t^{t+1} f(t+1)dx \leq \sum_{t=1}^{N-1}  \int_t^{t+1} f(x)dx$?

Comment: No.  Both parts are wrong; check your indices.

Answer (score 1):

The left direction is correct. An alternative way to prove this is using the [Cauchy condensation test.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

The right direction is not correct. You say: for $0 < p \le 1$ the series $\sum_n 1/n^p$ is divergent but you did not prove this!

Alternatively, you can also use the integral test or the Cauchy condensation test for this direction.

Comment: Really? Especially for the right direction?

Comment: I was too fast. You assume what you want to prove in that direction. I will edit my answer acoordingly.

Comment: It's okay. Now, how to show the right direction if mine was wrong?

Comment: @user795084 See my edited answer.

Comment: Done. Well, I not prove it here, but I was prove it then. So, I'm supposing that here I was proved it.

Comment: Wait. I'll write my proof so you and all can see that that series is divergent.

Comment: See my edited post.

Comment: Since I was proved it, now I'm done?

Comment: @user795084 Looks better now. But did you prove that $\sum_n n^{-1}$ diverges?

Comment: Is it must to be proven? Since I can use the unboundedness of $1/n$.

Comment: On the other hand, yes I did prove it.

Comment: @user795084 $\{1/n\}$ is not unbounded.

Comment: Really? Why is it not bounded?

Comment: It is bounded, because it is convergent...

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you may use:

Consider $p \leq 0$ first. In this case, $\frac{1}{n} = n^{-1} \geq 0$. The limit of this implies that it doesn't converge to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and so $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$ does not converge.

Now assume $p > 0$. Then $\frac{1}{n^p}$ is a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers. By applying the Dyadic criterion, we have:

$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges iff $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 2^n \frac{1}{(2^n)^p}$ converges.

And so $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (2^{1-p})^n$.

Let $q = 2^{1 - p}$ then the sum converges iff $q = 2^{1 - p} < 1$, which is iff $p > 1$.